# How to return both bool & string Result from a function in Rust?

Tags: rust, error-handling

I have a function: `f() -> Result<bool>` but it internally has more information as a string which I wanna return in the result as well along with the bool.

So my desired function signature is something like: `f() -> Result<bool, String>`. How can I achieve this? A small example would be very helpful.

Comment: What's wrong with a tuple? `Result<(bool, String), MyError>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`Result`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html) type returns one type for an error, and another for success. In the example you posted, `f` returns a `bool` if the function completed as intended, or a `String` if there was a failure along the way.

If you don't want to create a struct to contain both parts of the data (which is probably a bit nicer to read), you should wrap your output in a [`tuple`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.tuple.html). Your function signature would then look like `f() -> Result<(bool, String), ()>`, which returns *both* types if an `Ok` is returned, and no data (unit type) on an error. Your function would then return something like `Ok((is_success, str_info))` or `Err(())` (notice the double parens in both the tuple case and unit type case).

Comment: But I also want to return a string error like: `Err("Error: invalid input")`. So the double parenthesis for Err won't work

Comment: @NewToCode In that case, you should use `Result<(bool, String), String>` and that allows a `String` to be returned with your `Err` enum as you've just written.